# Series voltage reference output voltage

Tags: voltage, reference

What is output voltage of series voltage reference IC (for example [MAX6100](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6100-MAX6107.pdf)) when input voltage is below minimum input voltage? Is it zero volts, or something else?

Didn't find answer to this from data sheets I was reading.

Thanks.

Comment: Ermmmm... Are you asking about LDOs?(Linear regulators)?

Comment: What is a series voltage reference IC? Can you supply a datasheet link for one?

Comment: With "series" voltage reference I mean for example MAX6100, opposite to "shunt" voltage reference. https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6100-MAX6107.pdf

Comment: No, it will just fall out of regulation.  At least that's what I've seen with other parts.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find the answer in the data sheet then you can't make any assumptions about what will happen. You might get zero volts as soon as the input voltage falls below the minimum specified value, or the regulator might give some output voltage that is close to the desired value. The behavior may be different for different manufacturers of the same basic part number, and it is likely to be different for different kinds of regulators.

Some readers here will tell you about their experience but you can't count on seeing the same thing in your application with your parts. The datasheet is the only authoritaritive source.